# HiveServer versus HiveServer2

Tags: hive, hiveql

I know that HiveServer doesnot support multi-client concurrency and authentication and is handled in HiveServer2.

I want to know how this is handled in HiveServer2 and why it doesnot support in HiveServer.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question is simple, which I got to know few days ago.

Each and every client has to be connected through THRIFT API in hiveserver or hiveserver2 which in turn launches the process to convert the client code to hive understandable code by launching language specific class libraries.

As everyone is aware, a process can be single or multi threaded. In hiveserver1, the process launched is single threaded as the class libraries doesnot support multi threads. In hiveserver2, these have been upgraded to multi thread class libraries and thus supports multiple sessions.

Related to security, please refer the link below
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/how-hiveserver2-brings-security-and-concurrency-to-apache-hive/

Thanks,
Sree